# How to count child table items with or without join to parent table using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I used SQLAlchemy to create a SQLite database which stores bibliographic data of some document, and I want to query the author number of each document.

I know how to do this in raw SQL, but how can I achieve the same result using SQLAlchemy? It is possible without using `join`?

Here is the classes that I have defined:

```
    class WosDocument(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'wos_document'

        document_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        unique_id = Column(String, unique=True)
        ......
        authors = relationship('WosAuthor', back_populates='document')

    class WosAuthor(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'wos_author'

        author_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

        document_unique_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('wos_document.unique_id'))
        document = relationship('WosDocument', back_populates='authors')

        last_name = Column(String)
        first_name = Column(String)
```

And my goal is to get the same result as this SQL query does:

```
     SELECT a.unique_id, COUNT(*) 
     FROM wos_document AS a 
     LEFT JOIN wos_author AS b 
     ON a.unique_id = b.document_unique_id 
     GROUP BY a.unique_id
```

I tried the codes below:

```
    session.query(WosDocument.unique_id, len(WosDocument.authors)).all()

    session.query(WosDocument.unique_id, func.count(WosDocument.authors)).all()
```

The first line raised an error, the second line doesn't give me the desired result, it return only one row and I don't recognize what it is:

```
[('000275510800023', 40685268)]
```

Since `WosDocument` Object has a one-to-many relationship `authors`, I supposed that I can query the author number of each document without using `join` explicitly, but I can't find out how to do this with SQLAlchemy.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think the relationship is wrong, try something like. `document = db.relationship(
        'Wos', primaryjoin='WosAuther.document_unique_id == WosDocument.document_id', backref='authers')` you can query document, and it would have a list contain many wosauther

Comment: @ShiheZhang Thanks. I can query a single document's authors by `wosdocument.authors` with my relationship, but I don't know how to query the author number count of each document.

Comment: what about `len(wosdocument.authors )`?

Comment: `SELECT a.unique_id, COUNT(*) 
     FROM wos_document AS a 
     LEFT JOIN wos_author AS b 
     ON a.unique_id = b.document_unique_id 
     GROUP BY a.unique_id` This query result puzzle me. if some document have no author the count(*) would still have 1.Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @ShiheZhang every document must have at least one author, even sometimes the author is anonymous (I have checked that). And `len(wosdocument.authors)` will raise an error if I put it into session.query(). But the `len() ` function works fine if I already fetched a document object

Comment: try `db.session.query(ParentTable.pk,func.count('*').label("count")).join(Childtable).group_by(ParentTable).all()` if Parent don't have child, would not have a tuple in list.

Comment: @ShiheZhang your code works! But I am still thinking if I can achieve the same goal without using `join()` explicitly? Because `wosdocument.authors` can do the `join()` work for me?

Comment: Without `join()` explicitly, then you need to handle `wosdocument.authors` as a field. The sqlalchemy won't know you want to query through two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have written the right relation in your model. Then the query would be like:

```
db.session.query(ParentTable.pk,func.count('*').label("count")).join(Childtable).group_by(ParentTable).all()
```

The detail of the document of the `join()` is
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join

If you don't `join()` explictly you would need to deal with something like `parent.relations` as a field.

Comment: Now I am more clear about how to use `join` in SQLAlchemy, Thanks! I thought that SQLAlchemy was smart enough to treat `parent.relations` as something like a "virtual field", because I can use `parent.relations` to get its children once I have got the parent. But seems I am wrong. Using a `join()` is a better practice, right?

Comment: It's smartly treating the relations as  "virtual field". However, you need to specify your desired result or you need to deal with the "virtual field".

Comment: I see. I enable the `echo` feature and see that the `join()` function has been translated into `JOIN` in SQL, how can I do `LEFT JOIN`? SQLAlchemy seems doesn't have it.

Comment: check the link I provided in the answer, the default join is `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: If I execute `session.query(WosDocument.authors).all()`, the translated SQL is `SELECT wos_document.unique_id = wos_author.document_unique_id AS authors 
FROM wos_document, wos_author`. Once executed, several GBs of data are writing to my disk, why would that happend?

Comment: @TomLeung It's quite unclear, you should post another question with your specific environment.